# How to handle duplicates when using minimum in combination with mutate in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame. I want to add two new columns with a minimum date from column date1 and a maximum date from column date2 for each ID and subgroup.

```
    ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)   
    subgroup <- c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b")
    date1<- c("2017-12-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-01-01", "2017-02-01", "2017-01-15", "2017-12-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-10-01", "2017-10-01")                           
    date2<- c("2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-01", "2019-01-01", "2019-02-01", "2019-01-15", "2018-12-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-01", "2018-10-01")                           

    df<- data.frame(ID, subgroup, date1, date2) 

    df$date1 <- as_date(df$date1)
    df$date2 <- as_date(df$date2)


    df<- df %>% group_by(ID, subgroup) %>% mutate(min_date1 = if_else(date1 == min(date1), date1, as.Date(NA))) 
    df<- df %>% group_by(ID, subgroup) %>% mutate(max_date2 = if_else(date2 == max(date2), date2, as.Date(NA))) 

ID subgroup date1      date2      min_date1  max_date2   
 1 a        2017-12-01 2018-12-01 NA         2018-12-01
 1 a        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 NA        
 1 b        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-10-01
 1 b        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-10-01
 2 a        2017-01-01 2019-01-01 2017-01-01 NA        
 2 a        2017-02-01 2019-02-01 NA         2019-02-01
 2 b        2017-01-15 2019-01-15 2017-01-15 2019-01-15
 3 a        2017-12-01 2018-12-01 NA         2018-12-01
 3 a        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 NA        
 3 b        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-10-01
 3 b        2017-10-01 2018-10-01 2017-10-01 2018-10-01
```

Sometimes no minimum date is returned because of the high number of rows with duplicates. How should I resolve this?

I want to convert this data frame to a data frame like this below. I want to have the minimum and maximum date for each ID.

```
ID a_min_date1 a_max_date2 b_min_date1 b_max_date2
1  2017-10-01  2018-12-01  2017-10-01  2018-10-01
2  2017-01-01  2019-02-01  2017-01-15  2019-01-15
3  2017-10-01  2018-12-01  2017-10-01  2018-10-01
```

Thank you.

Comment: The `NA` values being returned have nothing to do with duplicates - your code says to return `NA` if the case is not equal to the min/max values.

Comment: @H 1: sometime even if there is a minimum date and a lot of duplicates, this function does not return the minumim that I would expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_by(ID, subgroup) %>%
  summarise(min_date1 = min(date1),
            max_date1 = max(date2)) %>%
  gather(key, val, min_date1:max_date1) %>%
  unite(new, subgroup, key) %>%
  spread(new, val)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Groups:   ID [3]
     ID a_max_date1 a_min_date1 b_max_date1 b_min_date1
  <dbl> <date>      <date>      <date>      <date>     
1     1 2018-12-01  2017-10-01  2018-10-01  2017-10-01 
2     2 2019-02-01  2017-01-01  2019-01-15  2017-01-15 
3     3 2018-12-01  2017-10-01  2018-10-01  2017-10-01
```

For count, try to do:

```
df %>%
  group_by(ID, subgroup) %>%
  summarise(min_date1 = min(date1),
            max_date1 = max(date2)
            ) %>% ungroup() %>%
  add_count(subgroup, name = "count") %>%
  gather(key, val, min_date1:max_date1) %>%
  mutate(countv = paste0("count_", subgroup)) %>%
  unite(new, subgroup, key) %>%
  spread(new, val) %>%
  spread(countv, count) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~ first(na.omit(.))))
```

Comment: How to add a new column after each min/max date with the number of rows for each subgroup (a, b, c, d)? so I want after the min/max date for a, a column called a_count, and after min/max date for b, a column called b_count.

Comment: Thanks arg0naut. I got the following error.  message: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a function
class:   `rlang_error`
  1. dplyr::group_by(., ID, subgroup)
  9. dplyr::summarise(...)
 10. dplyr::ungroup(.)
  1. dplyr::add_count(., subgroup, name = "count")
  9. tidyr::gather(., key, val, min_date1:max_date1)
 10. dplyr::mutate(., countv = paste0("count_", subgroup))
  1. tidyr::unite(., new, subgroup, key)
  9. tidyr::spread(., new, val)
 10. tidyr::spread(., countv, count)
  1. tidyselect::vars_pull(names(data), !!enquo(value))

Comment: Not sure what could be the reason.. For me it works fine - perhaps for you the problem is that you don't have the newest version of `dplyr` installed. Try re-installing it.

Comment: After I reinstalled dplyr, it works as I had expected. Many thanks!

Comment: after joining 4 datafarmes with min and max dates per subgroup, the final dataframe has the following columns:
a_min_date1_df1
a_min_date1_df2
a_min_date1_df3
a_min_date1_df4

I want to add a new column called with min and max from this 4 df
I have tried this and it works, but the df has more than 500 subgroups which I could not do manually for each. 

mutate(df, a_min= pmin(a_min_date1_df1, a_min_date1_df2, a_min_date1_df3, a_min_date1_df4, na.rm=TRUE),  a_max= pmax(a_max_date1_df1, a_max_date1_df2, a_max_date1_df3, a_max_date1_df4, na.rm=TRUE)

Comment: So, I started to replace the column names with

mutate(df, a_min= pmin(starts_with("a_") & ends_with(min_date), na.rm=TRUE), 
a_max= pmax(starts_with("a_") & ends_with(min_date), na.rm=TRUE))

But of course, this does not work. How should I fix this?

Comment: @ arg0naut: the adjusted script for count gives the number of all rows for each subgroup. How to adjust this that I can see the number of row for each ID of each subgroup? Thank you

Comment: Just add ID in the add_count statement. For the pmin and pmax, this is a different issue - I'd suggest you open a new topic.

Comment: I added ID to add_count, but I got only "1" as an output. I think I have to move the add_count before summzrize, because I want to know the number of all records (number of rows) for each ID before I apply min and max. I tried this but does not work.

Comment: Indeed, adding `add_count(ID, subgroup, name = "count")` at the beginning after `df %>%` should work, not sure why it doesn't!

Comment: I did what you said, but I still get the following error:                                            
Error: `var` must evaluate to a single number or a column name, not a function

Comment: Have re-run again, and don't see where it could come from :/ Works for me..

Comment: I add the count function before and it works. Thank you!

Comment: df <- df %>% add_count(subgroup, name = "count")                                                                  
df %>%
group_by(ID, subgroup, count) %>%
  summarise(min_date1 = min(date1),
            max_date1 = max(date2)
            ) %>% ungroup() %>%
gather(key, val, min_date1:max_date1) %>%
  mutate(countv = paste0("count_", subgroup)) %>%
  unite(new, subgroup, key) %>%
  spread(new, val) %>%
  spread(countv, count) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  summarise_all(list(~ first(na.omit(.))))